# make folder in php doesn't work correctly

Tags: php

I use below code for creating dir in server. It was working before. I changed sometimes permissions and true or false now This code just create a folder 'imei' with 300. What's problem?

```
$file_path = "uploads/".$_GET['imei']."/".$_GET['kind'];

    if (!file_exists($file_path)) {
    mkdir($file_path, 0744,true);
}
```

Comment: Running the browser you must have full permission (0777), now execute in ssh or ftp works correctly

Comment: @Dexxtz this is not necessarily true. If apache owns the folder, it should be able to write as well.

Answer (score -1):

```
$file_path = "uploads/".$_GET['imei']."/".$_GET['kind'];

    if (!file_exists($file_path)) {
    mkdir($file_path, 0744,true);
}
```

If its creating a folder now called "imei", you're either missing $_GET imei and $_GET kind. Make sure you're passing in the $_GET variables correctly. You're code is ok.